# Camel 2.15.2 / netty3: "java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument" from DatagramChannelImpl.send0()

Tags: linux, udp, apache-camel, netty, socketexception

I have an Apache Camel route that consumes from **netty:udp**, optionally sends a UDP response back to the UDP client (if requested), and produces to a Kafka topic.  I'm occasionally getting the below **java.net.SocketException** which is causing netty to stop listening on the configured UDP port. I guess what's concerning me is that all socket code is camel-netty, and this seems like a severe issue (i.e. stopping the associated netty UDP listener for the route, which I've verified via the Linux netstat command).

- I'm currently testing JVM execution with **-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true**, as other posts have recommended,
  but my concern is that the "Invalid argument" SocketException only happens infrequently, so not sure that
  setting  **-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true** will really solve the issue?
- I wonder if upgrading to **[camel-netty4](http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html)** would solve this issue?  I've written no socket code of my own, it's all Camel/netty.

I'm running on a Linux physical server with Java 1.7 and RHEL-6.  Any thoughts greatly appreciated!!!

**Here's my route XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route startupOrder="104" customId="true" id="ROUTE_ID_RAW_DTC_EVENTS" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <from uri="netty:udp://talend-es-edge-01.kiad0.s.mission.net:62265?serverPipelineFactory=#DTC_SERVER_PIPELINE_FACTORY_ROUTE_ID_RAW_DTC_EVENTS&amp;keepAlive=true&amp;sync=true&amp;orderedThreadPoolExecutor=false&amp;receiveBufferSize=8388608&amp;sendBufferSize=8388608&amp;allowDefaultCodec=false&amp;disconnectOnNoReply=false&amp;receiveBufferSizePredictor=8192"/>
        <setProperty propertyName="CamelCharsetName" id="setProperty10">
                <expressionDefinition>iso-8859-1</expressionDefinition>
        </setProperty>
        <threads poolSize="7" maxPoolSize="14" threadName="threads_ROUTE_ID_RAW_DTC_EVENTS" callerRunsWhenRejected="true" id="threads3">
                <wireTap uri="netty:udp://abinitio-edge-02.kiad0.s.mission.net:62265?clientPipelineFactory=#DTC_CLIENT_PIPELINE_FACTORY_ROUTE_ID_RAW_DTC_EVENTS&amp;sync=false&amp;sendBufferSize=8388608&amp;allowDefaultCodec=false" customId="true" id="ROUTE_ID_RAW_DTC_EVENTS_MIRROR"/>
                <multicast parallelProcessing="true" id="multicast3">
                        <to uri="seda:SEDA_TOP_102?size=100000&amp;concurrentConsumers=10&amp;waitForTaskToComplete=Never&amp;failIfNoConsumers=true&amp;timeout=10000" id="to8"/>
                        <to uri="seda:SEDA_ACK_103?size=100000&amp;concurrentConsumers=10&amp;waitForTaskToComplete=IfReplyExpected&amp;failIfNoConsumers=true&amp;timeout=10000" customId="true" id="ROUTE_ID_RAW_DTC_EVENTS_TO_FIRST_URIS"/>
                        <setProperty propertyName="CamelCharsetName" id="setProperty11">
                                <expressionDefinition>iso-8859-1</expressionDefinition>
                        </setProperty>
                </multicast>
        </threads>
</route>
```

**Here's the stack trace showing the SocketException**:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:433) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramWorker.writeFromUserCode(NioDatagramWorker.java:212) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioDatagramPipelineSink.java:97) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:725) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.doEncode(OneToOneEncoder.java:71) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:59) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:704) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:252) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.write(NioDatagramChannel.java:299) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty.NettyHelper.writeBodyAsync(NettyHelper.java:93) [camel-netty-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty.NettyProducer.process(NettyProducer.java:263) [camel-netty-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.WireTapProcessor$1.call(WireTapProcessor.java:119) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.WireTapProcessor$1.call(WireTapProcessor.java:113) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_75]
[2015-09-04 21:45:02,532] WARN  [New I/O worker #49] Caused by: [org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException - Cannot write response to /188.122.39.102:0. Exchange[Message: ]. Caused by: [java.net.SocketException - Invalid argument]]

org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: Cannot write response to /188.122.39.102:0. Exchange[Message: ]. Caused by: [java.net.SocketException - Invalid argument]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty.handlers.ServerResponseFutureListener.operationComplete(ServerResponseFutureListener.java:53) [camel-netty-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:431) [netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:417) [netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:384) [netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramWorker.write0(NioDatagramWorker.java:319) [netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromTaskLoop(AbstractNioWorker.java:151) [netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioChannel$WriteTask.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:335) [netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391) [netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315) [netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramWorker.run(NioDatagramWorker.java:343) [netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.sendFromNativeBuffer(DatagramChannelImpl.java:532) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(DatagramChannelImpl.java:494) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(DatagramChannelImpl.java:473) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SocketSendBufferPool$UnpooledSendBuffer.transferTo(SocketSendBufferPool.java:207) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramWorker.write0(NioDatagramWorker.java:281) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    ... 11 more
[2015-09-04 21:45:02,535] WARN  [pool-17-thread-23] Closing channel as an exception was thrown from Netty. Caused by: [java.net.SocketException - Invalid argument]

java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.sendFromNativeBuffer(DatagramChannelImpl.java:532) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(DatagramChannelImpl.java:494) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(DatagramChannelImpl.java:473) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SocketSendBufferPool$UnpooledSendBuffer.transferTo(SocketSendBufferPool.java:207) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramWorker.write0(NioDatagramWorker.java:281) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromTaskLoop(AbstractNioWorker.java:151) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioChannel$WriteTask.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:335) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramWorker.run(NioDatagramWorker.java:343) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) ~[netty-3.9.6.Final.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_75]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the camel-netty4  UDP for sometime now with no such problems. I would recommend you to use the camel-netty4 unless you have some compelling reason to stick around to using the camel-netty(netty3)